# How can RavenDB patch JSON objects?

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

Using Raven Studio's patch interface, I have the following patch script:
this.Market = this.Market.replace(" Los Angeles","Los Angeles")
to remove a prepended space.

Which would be fine for a field with single-value strings, but my data is structured as a JSON object:
"Market": [
        " Los Angeles",
        "Chicago",
        " New York City"],

And running the patch throws the error, "TypeError: Object has no method 'delete'." How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var m= this.Market;
for(var i=0; i < m.length; i++) {
this.Market[i] =  m[i].replace("Los Angeles","Los Angeles");
}
```